# Erroneous string manipulation in presence of special characters (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I encode username strings before inserting them into my web app's backend (used for lexicographically ordered search later on).

The algorithm for the encoding entails appending to the username, the numeric position of all **uppercase letters** identified while parsing the username. The position is encoded with a leading zero (if it's single digit) and can be a maximum of two digits. This implies I can represent strings of upto 100 length.

E.g. if the username is `PinKFloyD79`, its encoding would be `00030408` (i.e. upper case characters were found in position `00`, `03`, `04` and `08`).

Ultimately, I turn the username into lowercase, append `**` to it as a separator, and then append the encoding. So `PinKFloyD79` becomes `pinkfloyd79**00030408`. The code (in Python 2.7) is:

```
def process_uname(username):
    position = 0
    encoding = "**"
    for l in username:
        if l.isupper():
            encoding += "{:0>2}".format(position)
        position += 1
    encoded_uname = username.lower()+encoding
    return encoded_uname
```

The problem is my code is skipping special characters when calculating the encoding. For instance, if the username is `Pink囧Floyd`, my code interprets `F` to be at `04` instead of `05`. Can someone help?

---

In case needed, here's my function that later **decodes** the username back into it's original self:

```
def decode_uname(encoded_uname):
    uname_and_code = encoded_uname.split("**")
    lower_case_uname = uname_and_code[0]
    code = uname_and_code[1]
    upper_case_positions = [int(code[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(code), 2)]
    decoded_username = ''.join(let.upper() if pos in upper_case_positions else let 
                               for pos, let in enumerate(lower_case_uname))
    return decoded_username
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  The code you've posted encodes `Pink囧Floyd` as `0007` when passed as a `str`, `0005` when passed as `unicode`.  Are you sure the special character is even in `username` when it's passed to `process_uname`?

Comment: This character `囧` has a length of 3, so the output I get is `'pink\xe5\x9b\xa7floyd**0007'` which seems to me correct, no?

Comment: @jwodder, in both case (`str` or `unicode`) I get the same result

Comment: @IronFist: can you try encoding `Black囧Death`? I'm getting `black囧death**0006`, which when I decode (via the decoding code I've provided), results in `Black囧death`.

Comment: I get `'black\xe5\x9b\xa7death**0008'` using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My encoding code wasn't working correctly - unable to catch the correct `len` of special characters. Ensuring each username is `utf-8` is what has worked:

```
def process_uname(username):
    position = 0
    encoding = "**"
    for l in username.encode('utf-8'):
        if l.isupper():
            encoding += "{:0>2}".format(position)
        position += 1
    encoded_uname = username.lower()+encoding
    return encoded_uname
```